# jQuery UI range slider - Both values in different form selector elements

Tags: jquery, element, bind

I have a range slider with two values. A minimum price and a maximum. I have two selector elements: one with minimum price and one with maximum. I would like these selector's to change according to the slider. I've accomplished to change input fields when the slider is being used, but I can't seem to get the slider to work with two selector elements. Here is my code:

```
     $(function() {
      $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
       range: true,
       min: 1,
       step: 1,
       max: 5,
       values: [ 1, 5 ],
       slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#min" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] );
        $( "#max" ).val( ui.values[ 1 ] );
       }
      });
      $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
       " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) + " price" );

     });
```

And the html:

```
<input type="text" name="minimum" id="edit-nightlyavg-min" value="1" /> 

<input type="text" name="maximum" id="edit-nightlyavg-max" value="10" />
```

How can I make the slider change my two selector elements?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because your selectors for your input elements are wrong.

Your input elements have `id="edit-nightlyavg-min" and id="edit-nightlyavg-max"` but you're using `$("#max")` and `$("#min")`

Comment: Or, I didn't understand your question at all. :P